# c# Drawing a Polygon with coordinates, calculate are and centroid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, area, centroid

I'm drawing an irregular polygon with coordinates, drawing it works, it's when I'm trying to calculate the area and centroid that errors are occurring.

namespace WpfApplication3

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Draw polygon

    public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Point[] curvePoints =
        {
        new Point(10, 10),
        new Point(13, 11),
        new Point(15, 30),
        new Point(17, 10),
        new Point(20, 10),
        new Point(30, 15),
        new Point(30, 30),
        new Point(60, 40),
        new Point(65, 55),
        new Point(40, 60),
        new Point(40, 65),
        new Point(58, 70),
        new Point(60, 60),
        new Point(90, 60),
        new Point(90, 85),
        new Point(70, 61),
        new Point(60, 85),
        new Point(30, 85),
        new Point(12, 80),
        new Point(12, 78),
        new Point(16, 75),
        new Point(13, 68),
        new Point(17, 65),
        new Point(6, 62),
        new Point(16, 60),
        new Point(28, 56),
        new Point(27, 45),
        new Point(15, 32),
        new Point(15, 50),
        new Point(5, 50),
        new Point(10, 40)
    };

        var pointCollection = new PointCollection(curvePoints);
        var polygon = new Polygon
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.GreenYellow,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Fill = Brushes.Blue,
            Points = pointCollection
        };

        const int cx = 200;
        const int cy = 150;
        polygon.Measure(new Size(cx, cy));
        polygon.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));


        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(cx, cy, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(polygon);

        _image.Source = bmp;

    }


    // Calculate area

    class Point { double X, Y; }
    double PolygonArea(Point[] polygon)
    {
        int i, j;
        double area = 0;
        for (i=0; i < polygon.Length; i++)
        {
            j = (i + 1) % polygon.Length;

            area += polygon[i].X * polygon[j].Y;
            area += polygon[i].Y * polygon[j].X;
        }

        area /= 2;
        return (area < 0 ? -area : area);
    }


    // Calculate Centroid

      Point centroid =

            polygon.points.Aggregate(
                new { xSum = 0.0, ySum = 0.0, n = 0 },
                (acc, p) => new
                 {
                    xSum = acc.xSum + p.X,
                    ySum = acc.ySum + p.Y,
                    n = acc.n + 1
                },
                acc => new Point(acc.xSum / acc.ySum / acc.n));

    public static object polygon { get; private set; }
}

}
```

The main error that is recurrent is CS1729: MainWindow.Point does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

So I'm guessing that I need a constructor that takes 2 arguments, I just don't know how add one in MainWindow.

Another error occurs in Calculate centroid, CS1061: object has no definition for 'points' and no extension method for 'points'. (using or assembly may be missing?)

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You have declared your own `class Point { double X, Y; }` in class MainWindow. Remove it and make sure that the `System.Windows` namespace is used.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `class Point { double X, Y; }` which declares a private class within your MainWindow Class. This overrides the System.Windows.Point which does take 2 arguments in the constructor. Not sure why you have that in your code. Remove that block of code.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed your class for Point is incomplete, asfaras a constructor is concerned. You should have something akin to the following:

```
 class Point
 {
     public double X;
     public doubly Y;

     public Point(x, y)
     {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
     }
 }
```

Notice too that I made the `X` and `Y` fields public - without that you cannot access these fields from without the class. But why don't you simply use the `System.Windows` namespace, which already contains a perfectly well defined `Point` structure....

Next you have a problem with polygon - not surprising that the definition of `polygon` is merely `object`. An `object` does not have a `points` field or property.

What I think you really want to call here is to operate on a list or array of `Point` members (just like you did in `PolygonArea`)